# Can't Change WooCommerce Coupon Label In Cart Totals

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

This has proven to be a challenge I can't figure out. I handled the renaming of "Coupon" to "Promo" pretty much everywhere else. However, the renaming of the WC LABEL that calls the name of the coupon and the LABEL is a lot harder.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about exactly:

[image: Screenshot]

I've pretty much renamed all the uses of "coupon" to "promo" site-wide. This one is making my hair fall out. Has anyone ever successfully changed this? What am I missing?

### Rename "Coupon" to "Promo" code below

```
// rename the coupon field on the cart page
function woocommerce_rename_coupon_field_on_cart( $translated_text, $text, $text_domain ) {
   // bail if not modifying frontend woocommerce text
   if ( is_admin() || 'woocommerce' !== $text_domain ) {
      return $translated_text;
   }
   if ( 'Coupon code:' === $text ) {
      $translated_text = 'Promo Code:';
   }
   return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'woocommerce_rename_coupon_field_on_cart', 10, 3 );

// rename the "Have a Coupon?" message on the checkout page
function woocommerce_rename_coupon_message_on_checkout() {
   return 'Have a Customer Code?' . ' <a href="#" class="showcoupon">' . __( 
      'Click here to enter your code', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_message', 
   'woocommerce_rename_coupon_message_on_checkout' );

// rename the coupon field on the checkout page
function woocommerce_rename_coupon_field_on_checkout( $translated_text, $text, $text_domain ) {
   // bail if not modifying frontend woocommerce text
   if ( is_admin() || 'woocommerce' !== $text_domain ) {
      return $translated_text;
   }
   if ( 'Coupon code' === $text ) {
      $translated_text = 'Promo Code';
   } elseif ( 'Apply coupon' === $text ) {
      $translated_text = 'Apply Code';
   }
   return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'woocommerce_rename_coupon_field_on_checkout', 10, 3 );
```

### WC Coupon Notices/Message code below

```
function woocommerce_coupon_message( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
   switch ( $translated_text ) {
      case 'Coupon' :
          $translated_text = __( 'Promo', 'woocommerce' );
          break;
      case 'promo' :
          $translated_text = __( 'promo', 'woocommerce' );
          break;    
      case 'Please enter a coupon code.' :
          $translated_text = __( 'Please enter a Promo code.', 'woocommerce' );
          break; 
      case 'Coupon code already applied!' :
          $translated_text = __( 'Promo code already applied!', 'woocommerce' );
          break; 
      case 'Coupon has been removed.' :
          $translated_text = __( 'Promo has been removed', 'woocommerce' );
          break; 
      case 'Coupon code applied successfully.' :
          $translated_text = __( 'Promo code applied successfully.', 'woocommerce' );
          break;              
   }
   return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'woocommerce_coupon_message', 20, 3 );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Hide 'Coupon: CODE' in cart totals and instead return generic 'Promo Code Applied'
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_label', 'woocommerce_change_coupon_label' );
function woocommerce_change_coupon_label() {
    echo 'Promo Code Applied';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nisse. I tried that way back when but when you do that it deletes the actual name of the coupon being used. I could use it like this but thought it best to keep it so the user can actually see which coupon they used.

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_label', 'woocommerce_change_coupon_label' );
function woocommerce_change_coupon_label($sprintf, $coupon) {
    return 'Promo ' . $coupon->code;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain *why* and *how* your code snippet provides an answer to the question? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately for WooCommerce it won't just handle every place and all the messages that WC outputs. Unless something's changed. I had to add several instances to finally get it to work.

Comment: btw: $coupon can be null, so `$coupon->code` would cause an error

Answer (score 2):

I found a solutions for all needs.
Works with WooCommerce v7.

```
function custom_cart_totals_coupon_label($sprintf, $coupon)
{
    $coupon_code = $coupon->get_code();
    $sprintf = '<span class="discount_label">'.__('Coupon', 'veganwebagency').':</span> <span class="discount_code">'.$coupon_code.'</span>';
    return $sprintf;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_label', 'custom_cart_totals_coupon_label', 10, 2);
```

Comment: woocommerce_change_coupon_label expects exactly 2 arguments. this code will throw Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError, see http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_label/

Comment: @jasie If you still need it - I updates the solution which works with the newest version of WooCommerce.