# WooCommerce Admin Order Page change Discount(s) label

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gettext, orders

In a recent update to WooCommerce, they have changed the word Discounts to Coupon(s). This is in the order total table. See this screenshot for > clarity https://prnt.sc/sq6xfh

I would like to change this back to Discounts wherever possible as it doesn't really make sense to say Coupons when you have actually applied a discount. Ideally, it would be great to show a Discounts and a Coupon(s) row if required as sometimes you may apply a coupon AND a discount.

For now, I am I trying to change the Discount(s) label as pointed out above in the screenshot.

I have found the code in the plugins core files and know I cannot change that, this is the code:

```
    </tr>
    <?php if ( 0 < $order->get_total_discount() ) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon(s):', 'woocommerce' ); ?></td>
            <td width="1%"></td>
            <td class="total">-
                <?php echo wc_price( $order->get_total_discount(), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) ); // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I am not sure how to change Coupon(s) to Discounts in the code above via my functions.php

Any help appreciated.
Cheers
Nik

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155637/cant-change-woocommerce-coupon-label-in-cart-totals `do_action('woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_label', 'your_function')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WordPress `gettext` hook this way:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'custom_strings_translation', 20, 3);
function custom_strings_translation( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
global $pagenow, $typenow;

    // Settings
    $current_text = "Coupon(s):";
    $new_text     = "Discount(s):";

    // Targeting admin single order pages
    if( is_admin() && in_array($pagenow, ['post.php', 'post-new.php']) && 'shop_order' === $typenow && $current_text === $text ){
        $translated_text =  __( $new_text, $domain );
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related answers:

- [Rename Woocommerce "Orders" admin submenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342948/rename-woocommerce-orders-admin-submenu/53343840#53343840)
- [Change admin dashboard WooCommerce widget title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55667388/change-admin-dashboard-woocommerce-widget-title/55668841?r=SearchResults&s=17|20.0684#55668841)